# What does '-a' do in Unix Shell scripting

Tags: unix, shell, operators, logical-operators

What does `-a` mean in the below line.

```
if [ "${FILE_SYSTEM}" != "xyz" -a "${FILE_SYSTEM}" != "abc" ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man test`

```
 EXPRESSION1 -a EXPRESSION2
              both EXPRESSION1 and EXPRESSION2 are true
```

Answer (score 5):

It means logical *and* operator.

If both the operands are true then condition would be true otherwise it would be false.

In your case the condition in the `if` will be true when variable `$FILE_SYSTEM` is not `xyz` and is not `abc`.

Answer (score 2):

In shell script test (open brace) it means "and," so if the file system var does not equal xyz AND does not equal abc, the test succeeds.

Comment: `[` is a bracket, `{` is a brace

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent to

```
if [ "$x" != "a" -a "$x" != "b" ]; then
    do_one_thing
else
    do_other_thing
fi
```

is

```
case "$x" in
    a|b) do_other_thing ;;
    *)   do_one_thing ;;
esac
```